# How to Enable , Disable checkbox column in Silverlight Datagrid based on my Data

Tags: silverlight, datagrid, checkbox

i have a silverlight datagrid where first column is a checkbox column.

which looks like this..

```
 <sdk:DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header ="Select" Binding="{Binding Path=IsChecked ,Mode=TwoWay}" ></sdk:DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
```

this would check or uncheck based on my binding property IsChecked.

i also have a Binding property IsCheckBoxEnabled.

Is it possible to enable disable the checkbox using this property.

something like this.

```
<sdk:DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header ="Select" IsReadOnly={Binding IsCheckBoxEnabled} Binding="{Binding Path=IsChecked ,Mode=TwoWay}" ></sdk:DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
```

though the above line doesn't work. Am I missing something? i don't want to handle it in code behind.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem:

[Silverlight, datagrid, autogenerated columns on modified column change cell visibility of content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058379/silverlight-datagrid-autogenerated-columns-on-modified-column-change-cell-visi)

This is how I found and fixed it.

Comment: Nope its the same thing..in the link that u suggest..its still bound on one proprty.. i have two properties..:(

Comment: I already have - the example is on the link. Change the converted to instead of saying if this then visible else its not.. to if that and this then checked else not..